# IOS corebluetooth Background mode notification

Tags: ios, notifications, core-bluetooth

Currently am working with the project using core bluetooth. In which am using background mode communication, am able to receive the notification when ever app running in background but we have only one service and one characteristics for data communication based on frame type we are able to identify the frames which is received.

For background mode i used this code

```
[centralManager connectPeripheral:activePeripheral options:@{CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnConnectionKey: @YES,
    CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey: @YES,
    CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnNotificationKey: @YES}];
```

its working fine for both event and session background.

Event background alert shows for every notification is there any way to hide the alert for every notification show only needed.

Thanks

Comment: I think I can help you, but only if you can articulate your question better. I don't really understand what your problem is, what you are trying to achieve and what is the current state of your app. Try editing your question and provide more information in a clearer way. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

In *event mode* the alerts are generated by the system and as long as your app is not activated, it can't do anything about them.

In *session mode* the app stays responsible for handling all these events. It receives all the callbacks just as in the foreground. If you want to minimize the disturbance of the user, you should take over the alert generation with this mode.

Comment: When the device is in session mode, is there a certain amount of time it can stay active?  How does it know to reconnect and begin communicating while in the background?

Comment: Your app will receive a callback and get about 8 seconds on every BLE event (connect, disconnect, discovery, notifications, etc.) but it cannot run otherwise. It must stay suspended otherwise. But there is no way to wake the app at a desired time. Only BLE events generated by the connected peer can do that.

Comment: @allprog the 8 seconds part is very interesting to [us](http://vibereel.com/).. where did you get that number from? Any official docs?

Comment: ok got it [from apple docs](https://goo.gl/qmLN5V): `Upon being woken up, an app has around 10 seconds to complete a task. Ideally, it should complete the task as fast as possible and allow itself to be suspended again. Apps that spend too much time executing in the background can be throttled back by the system or killed.`